# Mysql query: How do I select ALL THE VOTES from ALL USERS FROM TODAY only when premium = 'yes'?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have tables:

```
 users
    with the fields id, premium
 votes
    with the fields userid, date.
```

How do I select ALL THE VOTES from ALL USERS FROM TODAY only when premium = 'yes'?

Comment: I want to have the number of the votes ONLY FOR premium users , from today

Comment: Is the `date` column a DATE or varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM VOTES v 
  JOIN USERS u ON u.id = v.userid
              AND u.premium = 'yes'
 WHERE v.date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: not working , gives Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /

Comment: @FinalDestiny  look for an error from the mysql_query call rather than the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from votes v, users u 
where v.userid = u.id and u.premium = 'yes' 
      and v.date = today()
```

Comment: Your question says "select all the votes", I was assuming there are some other fields in `votes` that you need. What exactly do you need to be counted? All votes per user? Or all votes over all users?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(a.id) from users a, votes b where a.id=b.userid and a.premium='yes' and b.date=CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT votes.* FROM users, votes WHERE users.Id = votes.userid WHERE premium='yes' AND date=DATE(NOW())
```